# Django email not sent, but executed in the console

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, smtp, signals

I have a sender for a password change signal. When I use endopint, it should send an email, but it only does it in the console.

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = '465'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "*******"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "******"
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "*******"
```

Console successfully outputs:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Subject: =?utf-8?b?0JTQvtCx0YDQviDQv9C+0LbQsNC70L7QstCw0YLRjCDQvdCwIHNpenpl?=
From: ********
To: kabiljanz0301@gmail.com
Date: Sat, 13 Feb 2021 16:30:12 -0000
Message-ID: 
 <161323381275.176437.7948111011454591000@kabiljan-Lenovo-IdeaPad-S340-14API>

/user/password_reset/?token=d2883b6ae18eb357ac1
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

what could be the problem?

Comment: EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SMTP backend¶**

The SMTP backend is the default configuration inherited by Django. If you want to specify it explicitly, put the following in your settings:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

If unspecified, the default timeout will be the one provided by socket.getdefaulttimeout(), which defaults to None (no timeout)
.

**Console backend¶**

Instead of sending out real emails the console backend just writes the emails that would be sent to the standard output. By default, the console backend writes to stdout. You can use a different stream-like object by providing the stream keyword argument when constructing the connection.

To specify this backend, put the following in your settings:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

This backend is not intended for use in production – it is provided as a convenience that can be used during development.

you are using console backend in setting. Replace the console backend with SMTP backend.

Answer (score 1):

change the "EMAIL_BACKEND" to this

```
 EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```